# Debug.Writeline

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

I am trying to write some messages to a text file using Debug.WriteLine("Message").

Here is the code.

```
Dim Tr As TextWriterTraceListener
Tr = New TextWriterTraceListener(System.IO.File.CreateText("Output1.txt"))
'Tr = New TextWriterTraceListener(System.Console.Out)
Debug.Listeners.Add(Tr)
Debug.WriteLine("Test Message")
```

I see the output1.txt file being created, but nothing is being written in the file.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `TextWriterTraceListener` buffers data and only writes it when the buffer is full, it is closed/disposed, or `Flush()` is called:

```
Dim Tr As TextWriterTraceListener
Tr = New TextWriterTraceListener(System.IO.File.CreateText("Output1.txt"))
'Tr = New TextWriterTraceListener(System.Console.Out)
Debug.Listeners.Add(Tr)
Debug.WriteLine("Test Message")
Tr.Flush()
```

Comment: @satish: that's because you flushed before you wrote the string. There's a toilet analogy here that I won't spell out for you.

Comment: Thanks Kent..that seem to be working. It was a simple one though!

Comment: Another question. When i run the program again, it says the file is being used by another process. How do i tackle that?

Answer (score 1):

You need to flush the buffer of the `TextWriterTraceListener`.

After writing to the trace listener you need to:

```
Tr.Flush();
```

See the documentation for [`Flush`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.textwritertracelistener.flush.aspx) on MSDN.

Answer (score 1):

You have to close and dispose the `TextWriterTraceListener`

```
Tr.Close()
Tr.Dispose()
```